# Natural spline with constant extrapolation in python

Tags: python, interpolation, spline

Ive been using the following code to interpolate with constant extrapolation in the past

```
from scipy import interpolate
f = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x,y, k = 3, ext = 3)
```

but the spline is 'not-a-knot' instead of 'natural'. Now, I know that it is possible to perform natural spline interpolation using

```
from scipy import interpolate
f = interpolate.CubicSpline(x,y, bc_type =  'natural')
```

but I don't see an option to add constant extrapolation.

Is there a function/way to do both features at the same time (natural+constant extrapolation)?

Thanks!

Comment: Ask this question at scipy github repo, they will help you. After that post their answer here.